# How to display the current date and time in grafana title panel

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I would like to display the date and time in the panel title of grafana

- Are there any direct methods like `${from:date:YYYY-MM-DD}` ?
- I want to display them either using grafana methods like above or use flux in influx(not sql)
- I am not looking for any workaround like creating a HTML panel above.

Answer (score 0):

- Create dashboard variable, which will use datasource to create string with current time, e.g. MySQL: `SELECT NOW()`, Flux has similar `NOW()` function
- Use that variable in the panel title